# Finding if a path is tangent to a level surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The question is as followed:

Consider the path $r(t)=<t,2\sin2t,2\cos2t>$

TRUE/FALSE: the path $r(t)$ is tangent to the level surface $f(x,y,z)=x^2-y^2+z=1$

---

I guess what's throwing me off is the lack of a specific point and the fact that it is a path equation with $t$ as a variable. I attempted this problem by parameterizing $r(t)$ with $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ and plugging that into $f(x,y,z)$ but that didn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: This seems to be a very hard problem. If the level surface were $x^2-y^2+z=2$, then you could see by inspection that $r(0)$ lies on the surface. And then you could see whether $\nabla f(0,0,1)\cdot r'(0) = 0$.  As it stands, you need to deal with some crazy trigonometry and algebra that can only be solved numerically.

Comment: I wonder if the path is really supposed to be $\langle 2\sin{2t},2\cos{2t},t\rangle$ or something along those lines.

Comment: @TedShifrin I looked through my notes again and saw this question gets MUCH simpler if you are given an initial condition $f(0)$ rather than trying to find it yourself. Luckily an answer key was given and the solution was simpler to answer than I anticipated.

Comment: The solution key is garbage. The question needs to be rewritten.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh yeah. Tell me about it. Just got to get through the course, so I only have to deal with this for a couple more days haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my answer key:

FALSE. At $t= 0$, we have $r(0) =〈0, 2 \sin\theta, 2 \cos \theta〉=〈0,0,2〉$. However,$f<0,0,2> = 0^2−0^2+2 =2 \neq 1$.  Thus the path is not contained in the level surface $f(x,y,z) = 1$.

Hope that helps someone.